# PHP determine if the word is in quotation marks

Tags: php

How do I get PHP to tell if a word is inside quotation marks?

Example:
Hi there, "my" name is ...

How do I find out if the word my is in quotation marks (double or single)?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $str = $_POST['textarea'];
    // determine if the word "my" is in quotation marks from the $str
}
```

Comment: We need more context here. Where is this string coming from?

Comment: @RussJ, the string is coming from a textarea

Comment: Can you post the code for that text area?

Comment: @RussJ, right now I only have PHP calling the textarea value after a post submission

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise this question will most certainly be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You want a regular expression that can detect the *word* you're searching for, wrapped in consistent quotes (same quote character each side).

Something like this

```php
$word = 'my';
$quoteCharacters = ['"', "'"];
$expression = sprintf('/([%s])%s\1/i',
    implode($quoteCharacters), preg_quote($word));
// produces something like /(["'])my\1/i

if (preg_match($expression, $str)) {
    echo "Found '$word' quoted";
}
```

The `\1` is a [back reference](https://www.php.net/manual/regexp.reference.back-references.php) to match the same quote character as found previously.

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/juHIi